# HQL IN operator, Array of Enums ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate, hql, classcastexception

Here is my stripped down class and enum.

```
class A
{
    @Enumerated (value = EnumType.STRING)
    AType type;
}

enum AType
{
    X,Y
}
```

if I run

```
query = FROM A a WHERE a.type = :type
query.setParameter("type", AType.X);
```

All is fine and dandy.

However if I do the following:

```
AType[] types = new AType[1];
types[0] = AType.X;
query = FROM A a WHERE a.type IN (:types)
query.setParameter("types", types);
```

I get:

```
Lcom.src.AType; cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
```

If I do:

```
Enum[] types = new Enum[1];
types[0] = AType.X;
query = FROM A a WHERE a.type IN (:types)
query.setParameter("types", types);
```

I get:

```
Ljava.lang.Enum; cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
query.setParameterList("types", types);
                  ^--
```

This should do it.

Comment: Such an obvious oversight on my part. Thanks!

Comment: The signature of the abovementioned method is setParameters(Object[] values, Type[] types) (Hibernate 3.5.4). This does not seem to fit. The method setParameterList(String name, Object[] vals) is the right one.

Answer (score 3):

query.setParameterList("types", types);