# Passing parameter to HQL

Tags: hibernate

I have one variable like `long[] ids = [10, 11]` and I am trying to fire query like this :

```
Query query2 = session.createQuery("update Employee e SET e.isLatest = false where e.id not in (:ids)");
query2.setParameter("ids", ids);
query2.executeUpdate();
```

But I am getting error like

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint <> character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can pass array variable in `NOT IN` parameter? Or Is there any other way for handling such query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set list of values as parameter into hiberante query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584898/how-to-set-list-of-values-as-parameter-into-hiberante-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
query2.setParameterList("ids", ids);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, it worked. But before that I converted `long[] ids to ArraList<long>`. As setParameterList needs collection parameter.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways

1) use of `setParameterList(,);` and pass collection

2) Use

```
query2.setParameter("ids", ids);
```

where `ids` is one string , which contains comma separated id

eg.

`String commaseperatedId="10,11".` 
and then

`query2.setParameter("ids", commaseperatedId);`

Answer (score 0):

I think `query2.setParameters("ids", ids);` [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5084193/432903).

### OR

Follow [Set array of parameters to hibernate query language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513423/432903)

```
query2.setParameterList("ids", ids);
```